# Python : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DatetimeIndexResampler'

Tags: python

I have a problem with the following syntax operator, why it doesn't work, how do I enter the dataframe?

```
flowrate = df_flow*A
flowrate
```

results.

```
eTime
2017-07-16 00:00:00   -0.002205
2017-07-16 00:01:00   -0.002205
2017-07-16 00:02:00   -0.002205
2017-07-16 00:03:00   -0.002205
2017-07-16 00:04:00   -0.002205
                     ...   
2017-07-22 23:55:00    0.004767
2017-07-22 23:56:00    0.004702
2017-07-22 23:57:00    0.004727
2017-07-22 23:58:00    0.004613
2017-07-22 23:59:00    0.004451
Freq: T, Name: Flowspeed, Length: 10080, dtype: float64
```

from the results of the evaluation, how to enter into the loop the volume of water in the range of days.

```
print('Volume from Flow Rate')
n = 0
z = 1
while (n <= 10037):

I = 0
for i in range (n, n+1440):
   I = I + flowrate.resample('D')
print('Hari ke- %i : %i'%( z, I))
z = z+1
n = n+1440
```

when I try to enter into the loop above, I find the following syntax

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DatetimeIndexResampler'
TypeError: %i format: a real number is required, not Series
```